# TWIG - loop through a string

Tags: twig

I have a variable page.stock which is set on the load as the string "3,4,5,6".

I want to loop through this variable. I tried:

```
{% for mysize in app.request.get(page.stock) %}

    <input type="radio" id="{{mysize}}" name="size" value="{{mysize}}" >
    <label for="{{mysize}}">{{mysize}}</label> 

{% endfor %}
```

and I also tried:

```
{% for mysize in page.stock %}

    <input type="radio" id="{{mysize}}" name="size" value="{{mysize}}" >
    <label for="{{mysize}}">{{mysize}}</label>   

{% endfor %}
```

Both with no luck. How do I iterate through the `,` delimited string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to [split](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) the string into a list:

```
{% for mysize in page.stock|split(',') %}
   <input type="radio" id="{{mysize}}" name="size" value="{{mysize}}" >
   <label for="{{mysize}}">{{mysize}}</label> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that,

I get 

The filter "split" does not exist in "partials/shoe/shoe-content.html" at line 25

Comment: Hi @StevenMoffat. What version of Twig are you using? Also, are you able to update to a newer version? The split filter was added in version 1.10.3 which was released 7 months ago.

Comment: Thanks Paulro...
The version of twig is bundled with stacy (stacyapp.com) appears to be from 2010 its a app folder of extensions, can I just add this function or try update the whole of twig ? is twig fully supportive of legacy code as my installation is based on my alts on assemblage plus on stacy !!!! which appears to be developed on twig - yaml :(

Comment: @StevenMoffat Do you see a file in extensions called twig-extensions.inc.php?

Comment: If so you can add an entry to the filters array, like: `'split' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'splitter'),`

Comment: Then define splitter like so: `function splitter($string, $delim = ' '){ return explode($delim, $string); }`

Comment: Thanks Paulpro - that resolved it, had to define the split function myself :) then used explode